# Rankings are incorrect

Tags: python

I'm ranking the top ten basketball players in the NBA via points, minutes, free throws, and efficiency. However, when I go to print the rankings the rankings are incorrect. It seems to be ranking them in terms of the value of each character in the numbers but I want them to be ranked by the highest amount to the lowest amount of those previously mentioned values.

My code:

```
def readData(filename):

    inputFile = open(filename, 'r')

    inputFile.readline()

    master_data_list = []

    for line in inputFile:
        master_data_list.append(line.split(","))

    return master_data_list

def points(master_data_list):

    pointList = []

    for player in master_data_list[:-3]:
        index = (player[1], player[2], player[6])
        pointList.append(index)

    return pointList

def minutes(master_data_list):

    minutesList = []

    for player in master_data_list[:-3]:
        index = (player[1], player[2], player[5])
        minutesList.append(index)

    return minutesList

def freethrows(master_data_list):

    freethrowsList = []

    for player in master_data_list[:-3]:
        index = (player[1], player[2], player[18])
        freethrowsList.append(index)

    return freethrowsList

def efficiency(master_data_list):

    effList = []

    for player in master_data_list:
        formula = int(((player[6] + player[9] + player[10] + player[11] + player[12])-((player[15] - player[16]) + (player[17] - player[18]) + player[13]))/(player[4]))
        index = (player[1], player[2], formula)
        effList.append(formula)

    return effList

def main():

    master_data_list = readData("player_career.csv")

    pointList = points(master_data_list)
    minutesList = minutes(master_data_list)
    freethrowsList = freethrows(master_data_list)
    #effList = efficiency(master_data_list)

    #got this code from 
    pointList = sorted(pointList, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)
    minutesList = sorted(minutesList, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)
    freethrowsList = sorted(freethrowsList, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)
    #effList = sorted(effList, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)

    print("Top 10 players based on total points scored.")
    for line in pointList[:10]:
        print(line[0], line[1]+"-"+line[2])
    print()

    print("Top 10 players based on total minutes.")
    for line in minutesList[:10]:
        print(line[0], line[1]+"-"+line[2])
    print()

    print("Top 10 players based on total free throws.")
    for line in freethrowsList[:10]:
        print(line[0], line[1]+"-"+line[2])
    print()

    """
    print("Top 10 players based on total efficiency.")
    for line in effList[:10]:
        print(line[0], line[1]+"-"+line[2])
    print()
    """
```

The output of the code:

Top 10 players based on total points scored.
Terrell Brandon-9994
Rony Seikaly-9991
David Vaughn-998
Buddy Jeannette-997
Irv Torgoff-997
Greg Ballard-9953
Ralph Simpson-9953
John Lucas-9951
Don Kojis-9948
Phil Chenier-9931

Top 10 players based on total minutes.
Fred Hoiberg-9976
Charlie Johnson-9972
Stewart Granger-996
Gary Gregor-996
Keith Bogans-9957
Al Wood-9939
Kenny Gattison-9930
Willis Bennett-993
Jack Molinas-993
Corie Blount-9925

Top 10 players based on total free throws.
Kurt Rambis-999
Charlie Scott-998
Walt Wesley-998
Albert King-996
Lucious Harris-994
Johnny Neumann-991
Frank Johnson-990
Mardy Collins-99
Calvin Garrett-99
Bob Lackey-99

I haven't done efficiency yet so it's not included.

Here's a sample of the input file:

[player stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoVhO.png)

If someone has an idea to get them to rank correctly, thanks.

Comment: Are your points stored as integers of strings? Looks to me like they are strings, so get sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input file contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this `key = lambda x: x[2]` into `key = lambda x: int(x[2])` to compare integers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the strings in your input into integers, like:

```
def points(master_data_list):

    pointList = []

    for player in master_data_list[:-3]:
        index = (player[1], player[2], int(player[6]))
        pointList.append(index)

    return pointList
```

Comment: With this I got an error: print(line[0], line[1]+"-"+line[2])
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Now change `line[2]` to `str(line[2])`.

Comment: The answer by @lenik is better.